# Finding maximum value for column among a subset of a data frame

Tags: r

Given a data frame `df` with columns `d`, `c`, `v`. How do I find the value of `d` for the maximum value of `v` among the *subset* of records where `c == "foo"`?

I tried this:

```
df[df$v==max(df$v) & df$c == "foo","d"]
```

But I got:

```
character(0)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yo can do as follows:

```
with(df, d[v== max(v[c=="foo"])])
```

EDITED:
If you want to get the value of `d` for all the levels of `c`:

```
library(plyr)
ddply(df, "c", subset, v==max(v))
```

Comment: Thanks. with(df, d[v== max(v[c=="foo"])]) is what I was looking for.

Comment: For my case, I actually did want to get the value of d for all the levels of c, but it told me "long vectors not supported yet" in R-3.1.2.  The file was kinda big, tho, so I solved it another way, but definitely an upvote!

Answer (score 1):

While Manuel's answer will work most of the time, I believe a more correct version would be:

```
with(df, d[v== max(v[c=="foo"]) & c=="foo"])
```

Otherwise it's possible to match a row which has `v==max` but is not in fact a subset of `c=="foo"`.